# How to make tight underlines that omit longer letters?

Tags: underline

Using `\underbar{Categorical}` produces

[image]

But how do I automatically produce `\underbar{Cate}g\underbar{orical}`, which looks like

[image]

I mean automatic in the sense that I don't have to single our the `g`, or other long letters like `y` and `j` etc.